# Only the last directive on an AngularJS page maintains it's binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got a couple directives that I intend to be reusable elements, so I'm using scope isolation.  Each directive has it's own dedicated controller which pulls it's data from mongo based on url.

The problem is that only the last directive on the page is showing the data to which it is bound.  Doesn't matter what order I put the directives in, only the last one works, and each one does work.  For ex I do get the customer dump into the log, but nothing shows up in {{ here }} unless it's the last directive in the page.

I'm fairly certain this is a scope issue, but these are meant to be isolated for reuse, so why would they be blanking each other out?

On the code...

**js**

```
.controller('getCustomerList',function(customerIOService){
    _this = this;
    _this.customers = {};
    customerIOService.list()
                    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                        _this.customers = data;
                    })
                    .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                        console.log('error Data :: ');
                        //console.log(data);
                        if(status == 403){
                            _this.error = 'You need to be logged in to view this page.';
                        }else{
                            _this.error = 'An error occured during the customer list request.';
                        }
                    });
})
.controller('getCustomerAppointments',function(customerIOService){
    _this = this;
    _this.appointments = {};
    customerIOService.getAppointments()
                    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                        _this.appointments = data;
                        //console.log(data);
                    })
                    .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                        console.log('error Data :: ');
                        //console.log(data);
                        if(status == 403){
                            _this.error = 'You need to be logged in to view this page.';
                        }else{
                            _this.error = 'An error occured during the appointments list request.';
                        }
                    });
})
.controller('getCustomerSingle', function(customerIOService) {
    _this = this;
    _this.customer = {};
    _this.updateSuccess = false;

    customerIOService.one()
                    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                        _this.customer = data;
                        console.log(data);
                    })
                    .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                        console.log('error Data :: ');
                        //console.log(data);
                        if(status == 403){
                            _this.error = 'You need to be logged in to view this page.';
                        }else{
                            _this.error = 'An error occured during the customer fetch request.';
                        }
                    });

    _this.update = function(){
        customerIOService.update(_this.customer)
                    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                        _this.customer = data;
                        _this.updateSuccess = true;
                    })
                    .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                        console.log('error Data :: ');
                        //console.log(data);
                        if(status == 403){
                            _this.error = 'You need to be logged in to view this page.';
                        }else{
                            _this.error = 'An error occured during the customer update.';
                        }
                    });
    }
})
.directive('customerList',function() {
    return {
      scope: {},
      restrict:'E',
      templateUrl: 'views/templates/customersList.html',
      replace: true,
      controller: 'getCustomerList',
      controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    };
})
.directive('customerSingle',function() {
    return {
      scope: {},
      restrict:'E',
      templateUrl: 'views/templates/customersSingle.html',
      replace: true,
      controller: 'getCustomerSingle',
      controllerAs: 'singleCustCtrl'
    };
})
.directive('customerAppointments',function() {
    return {
      scope: {},
      restrict:'E',
      templateUrl: 'views/templates/customersAppointmentsList.html',
      replace: true,
      controller: 'getCustomerAppointments',
      controllerAs: 'custApptCtrl'
    };
})
```

**Parent html**

```
<section>
    <div class="sectionHeader oswald font-light panel panel-default panel-body panel-success text-center">Customer Update</div>

    <div class="panel panel-default panel-body panel-success">
        <customer-single></customer-single>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default panel-body panel-success">
        <customer-appointments><customer-appointments/>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default panel-body panel-success">
        <customer-list><customer-list/>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Directive html**

```
<span>
    <a href="/appointments/create/{{custApptCtrl.customer._id}}">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-stack-1x "></i>
            </span>
            Add Appointment
        </a>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Caregiver</th>
        <th>Start</th>
        <th>End</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="appt in custApptCtrl.appointments">
        <td>{{ appt.employee.lastName }}, {{ appt.employee.firstName }}</td>
        <td>{{ appt.startDate }}</td>
        <td>{{ appt.endDate }}</td>
        <td><a href="/appointments/{{appt._id}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></td>
      </tr>
      </a>
   </tbody>
</table>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `controllerAs` syntax seems a little fishy to me, can you give this a try instead:

controller:

```
    app.controller('xyz', function() {
       var xyzVm = this;
      // and now use this xyzVm instead of _this everywhere in the controller
    });
```

and then in your directive

```
.directive('customerList',function() {
    return {
      scope: {},
      restrict:'E',
      templateUrl: 'views/templates/customersList.html',
      replace: true,
      controller: 'xyz',
      controllerAs: 'xyzVm'
    };
})
```

so now your template can use `xyzVm.appointments` within the repeater

Comment: Well dang. That was easy.  Nail on the head.  Will mark it as answered in 3 minutes.  Am I correct in assuming _this was being rewritten per dom injection?